# Split Website into 3 responsive triangles

Tags: html, css

Hey I am searching for a solution to split my front page of my website into 3 responsive triangles. All theses triangles should have an image inside and some text but it doesn't work that well...

All ready tried to work with 'border' or 'transform'. Also used 'vw' and 'vh' instead of percentage.

CSS for the first "main" triangle:

```
.triangle {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.triangle:before {
  background-size: cover;
    content:"";
    display:block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-g-1920-1080-10.jpg");
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform-origin:0 0;

}
```

The triangle should get the whole width of the display resolution and height too.

Answer (score 0):

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  border: .5vw solid black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: .2vw;
  width: 33%;
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
}

#left {
  background-color: green;

}

#middle {
  background-color: orange;
}

#right {
  position: absolute;
  right: .2vw;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

> **Please see [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Omar_Ahmed_Happy/v5red4zb/2/)**